# JSTL - size (length) of a list without using function

Tags: list, size, jstl

Is it possible to get the size (length) of a collection (list) **`WITHOUT`**`using functions` ?

The only way I could do now is:
To create a method to get the totalSize of list in my Java class and to use it in my JSP!

Answer (score 0):

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" prefix="fn"%>
...
<c:out value="${fn:length(yourCollection)}"/>
```

Comment: I do not have permission to use jstl functions. That's why I asked and clearly mentioned as WITHOUT using functions. Thanks.